# How to update an object with another object value in JPQL using Spring JPA

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm facing a problem in JPQL. I have two entities like below

```
class Employee{

  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private Department department;

  public void setId(Long id){
    this.id = id;
  }

  public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void setDepartment(Department department){
    this.department = department
  }

  public Long getId(){
    return this.id;
  }

  public String getName(){
    return this.name;
  }

  public Department getDepartment(){
    return this.department;
  }
}
```

and...

```
class Department{

  private Long id;
  private String name;

  public void setId(Long id){
    this.id = id;
  }

  public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Long getId(){
    return id;
  }

  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }
}
```

Now i need to update an `Employee`'s department. I have tried the query below.

```
update Employee e set e.department.id = 'XXX' where e.id in (?1);
```

This is giving exception like

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations.
```

Can you please guide me, How can i solve this issue?

Cheers,
Teja.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Spring Data JPA repository interface do:

```
interface EmployeeRepository extends Repository<Employee, Long> {

  @Modifying
  @Transactional
  @Query("update Employee e set e.department = ?2 where e = ?1")
  void updateDepartment(Employee employee, Department department);
}
```

Be sure to realize:

- If you're executing modifying queries, you're bypassing lifecycle callbacks on the entities. This is a fundamental characteristic of JPA.
- If you need lifecycle callbacks applied, load the `Employee`, manually set the `Department`, store the `Employee`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true) 
@Transactional
@Query("update Employee e set e.department = ?2 where e = ?1")
void updateDepartment(Employee employee, Department department);
```

*@Modifying* will separate it from select queries.

*@Transactional* will help transaction with the database.

*@Query* is the same old query execution.